# Save a document in Alfresco shared folder via Rest API

Tags: alfresco, apache-httpclient-4.x, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm try to upload a file to the shared folder...
This is my code.

```java
// using httpclient-4.5

Path filePath = Paths.get("C:/afile.txt");
String ticket = getTicket();  //  get a ticket via /alfresco/service/api/login...

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload?alf_ticket=" + ticket);
MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

StringBody descriptionBody = new StringBody("a test", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
StringBody siteId = new StringBody("company_home", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);    //  how can upload the file 
StringBody containerid = new StringBody("/Shared", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);    //  in the shared folder??

entity.addBinaryBody("filedata", filePath.toFile());
entity.addPart("siteid", siteId);
entity.addPart("containerid", containerid);

post.setEntity(entity.build());

CloseableHttpResponse postResponse = client.execute(post);

// ...
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Why not do it via [CMIS](http://cmis.alfresco.com/)?

Comment: I'm going to have a look. Gagravarr, do you know a good tutorial to manage uploads and templates. Next step is to upload a file/piece of text and create a document using an Alfresco template

Comment: There's loads, look on the Alfresco CMIS site, or the Apache Chemistry site, or Jeff Pott's blog, or the Alfresco forums...